# Is this algorithm is true for a directed unweighted graph and how can i make it undirected?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Graph {// in the first line we will take the number of nodes and
                    // edges
  static ArrayList<Integer>[] graph;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    int nodes = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    int edges = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    graph = new ArrayList[nodes];

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
      graph[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < edges; i++) {
      StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
      graph[Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken())].add(Integer.parseInt(st2
          .nextToken()));
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Algorithm to do what?

Answer (score 0):

Graphs can easily be made undirected by adding the reverse to each edge the graph. For example, if the graph contains the edge (nodeA , nodeB , weigth), you have to add the edge (nodeB, nodeA , weight) aswell. The actual implementation of this depends upon the implementation of the graph itself.